# Git push branch-a then merge with master then push to master doing nothing?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, bitbucket

So my team follows this flow.

1. git checkout -b BRA-123

*make changes*

2. git add .
3. git commit -am "BRA-123 - made some changes"
4. git push origin BRA-123
5. git checkout master
6. git merge BRA-123
7. git push origin master

Then I get

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

The problem is after I push to `BRA-123` it uses up the commit, and I cant push to both branches at this point without making changes directly in master.

I am not sure why this is? Does anyone know why?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. What is "it uses up a commit" mean?
When you say "I can't push to both branches at this point without making changes directly in master", what does that mean? (why can't, you? what happens?)

Was the merge successful?  What would help is if you show gitx screenshot after each step. Also reflog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your step 6 (`git merge BRA-123`) results in a "fast-forward" merge.  That is, at step 3, your commit graph looks something like this:

```
              C   <-- BRA-123
             /
... <- A <- B     <-- master
```

Here, new commit `C` points back to its parent commit `B`; `B` points back to `A`, and so on with older commits.

Now, when I say "your commit graph" I mean **your** commit graph, in your own repository on your machine, not the shared repository on `origin` to which you will `git push`.

In *your* repository, the label `master` points to commit `B` and the label `BRA-123` points to commit `C` (the single letters here stand in for big ugly 40-character SHA-1s like `81e0842b2eb89a882eaa9e11aba7f3d7260bcc75`).

Let's draw that same commit graph without bothering with the labels, for a moment:

```
... <- A <- B <- C
```

I didn't need to put `C` on a separate line this time because I don't need room for branch labels.

This part, with just the commits and their own arrows, is what git is counting when you see `Total 0 (delta 0)`.  This is because the labels sit outside the graph, and git is counting the compression it does on the graph.

Now, when you do your first `git push origin BRA-123`, this is short for the full-length version, `git push origin BRA-123:BRA-123`, which means "Please Internet-call (or otherwise connect to) the machine listed on the URL that goes with the remote `origin` and give to *his* git repo any commits and other graph bits needed so that he can set *his* `BRA-123` to point to the same commit my `BRA-123` points-to."

"His repo", of course, has just the series of commits ending in `... <- A <- B`.  So your git talks with his git and they decide that your side must send commit `C`, and probably some bits of files and such as well.  Those add up to something other than zero, so you get a nonzero `Total 3` or whatever.  Your git sends that over, then his git checks whether it's OK to set (or create) branch `BRA-123` to point to commit `C`.  Assuming it is, his git will do that and your git gets a success report and all is well.

Now you go on to step 5 (`git checkout master`) and then 6 (`git merge BRA-123`).  With step 6 you tell your git to find the common merge-base between the current tip of master, and the tip of `BRA-123`—i.e., find the most recent shared commit between commit `B` and commit `C`.  That's just commit `B` itself, which means that `master` can be moved in a "fast-forward" fashion.  If you don't prohibit this fast-forwarding, git does it that way: it simply erases the old label `master` and points `master` to commit `C`, giving you this:

```
... <- A <- B <- C   <-- BRA-123, master
```

That is, both labels point to commit `C`.  (This is perfectly normal in git-ese.  Other source systems might always create a separate merge commit, even when fast-forwarding is possible; git *can* do that, but doesn't by default.)

Now you go on to step 7 (`git push origin master:master`), asking your git to call up the other git again.  Your git does so, and it talks with his git, and they discover that no commits or other stuff needs to be sent: `Total 0`.  Then your git asks his git to change his `master` to point to commit `C`, which he already has.

This either succeeds (his git fast-forwards `master` from commit `B` to commit `C`) or fails, and as usual, you will get a separate indication of failure, if there is a failure.  Probably it succeeds.  It takes no new objects added to the commit graph, though, since you're just asking the other git to do a quick fast-forward of its `master` branch-label.

Comment: wow thanks for the explanation, I like to think I understand most of what you are saying, but I can't figure out how I can solve the fast forward?

Comment: Excellent answer! Since this is tagged with "bitbucket", you should also be able to go to the GUI there and confirm that `master` now has the commits and code that had been in `BRA-123`.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?  Do you want to *avoid* fast-forward merges?  If so, use `git merge --no-ff` at the time you do the merge: that tells git to make a new merge commit even if it's possible to use a branch-label fast-forward operation instead.  (There's also `git merge --ff-only`, telling git to allow *only* the fast-forward operation: if the merge requires a real merge commit, fail instead.)

Comment: Cool, it's just weird because my other team members follow the same steps I have given in my answer without a problem, so I was just confused. In my case it was not working as my expected behavior, that is what I mean by "solve".